# JS: Correct require syntax instead using import

Tags: javascript

Normaly I'm using ES6 syntax to import things from another file:

**target.js**

```
import { articles } from '/imports/fixtures.js'

console.log(articles.main)
```

**fixtures.js**

```
export const
  articles = {
    main: { _id: '1234', title: 'anything' }
  }
```

Now I need to use the fixtures.js file in some testing modules, which needs the require syntax.

But this would not work:

```
var { articles } = require('/imports/fixtures.js')
```

What is the correct syntax for this?

Comment: Are you using WebPack or something to bundle your JS?

Comment: This should work in ES6 (with babel). What is your stack / javascript version?

Comment: How are you transpiling the export syntax in `fixtures.js`?

Comment: Have you tried `var articles = require('/imports/fixtures.js').articles`?

Comment: `var { articles } = require('./imports/fixtures.js')` ?

Comment: "*this would not work*" - what is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Destructuring assignement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) is a recent feature, if your version of javascript (I guess of nodejs) is prior to ES2015, you could use:

```
var articles = require('/imports/fixtures.js').articles
```

**N.B**: NodeJS supports of desctructuring assignment [start with **v6**](/a/17379714/6320039).

Answer (score 0):

if you are exporting articles as a single object, you need to receive as a single object.

**For This**

```
export const
  articles = {
    main: { _id: '1234', title: 'anything' }
  }
```

**Use This**

```
var articles = require('/imports/fixtures.js');
```

**For main**
This will open the articles object and take out main and store it in a variable main in target.js.

```
var {main} = require('/imports/fixtures.js');
```